# using match to check both character and function type objects

Tags: r, ggplot2, user-defined-functions

I am writing a custom function that plots a smoothing line and displays subtitle as "linear model" only when the `geom_smooth` parameters are all linear (i.e. `method = "lm"` and `formula = y ~ x`). This involves checking what the user inputs for these two arguments. The complicated aspect of checking the input is that the `method` argument can be entered either as a character (`"lm"`) or as a function (`MASS::rlm`) and this is where the function fails.

How can I get this to work?

Here is a `reprex`:

```r
# for reproducibility
set.seed(123)
library(tidyverse)
library(mgcv)

# defining a function to plot smooth line
scatter_lm <- function(df, x, y, formula = y ~ x, method = "lm") {
  if (as.character(deparse(formula)) != "y ~ x" ||
    !any(method %in% c("lm", stats::lm))) {
    subtitle <- "non-linear model"
  } else {
    subtitle <- "linear model"
  }

  # creating the plot
  ggplot(df, aes(!!rlang::enquo(x), !!rlang::enquo(y))) +
    geom_smooth(formula = formula, method = method) +
    labs(subtitle = subtitle)
}

# different `formula` (works)
scatter_lm(mtcars, wt, mpg, y ~ log(x))
```

[image]

```r
# `method` entered as a character (works)
scatter_lm(mtcars, wt, mpg, y ~ x, "gam")
```

[image]

```r
# `method` entered as a function (doesn't work)
scatter_lm(mtcars, wt, mpg, y ~ x, MASS::rlm)
#> Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L): 'match' requires vector arguments
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this solution is a bit convoluted, but it works:

```
scatter_lm <- function(df, x, y, formula = y ~ x, method = "lm") {
  a <- paste(deparse(method), collapse = "") 
  if (as.character(deparse(formula)) != "y ~ x" ||
      if (class(method) == "function") {
        a != paste(deparse(lm), collapse = "")
      } else method != "lm") {
    subtitle <- "non-linear model"
  } else {
    subtitle <- "linear model"
  }

  #creating the plot
  ggplot(df, aes(!!rlang::enquo(x), !!rlang::enquo(y))) +
    geom_smooth(formula = formula, method = method) +
    labs(subtitle = subtitle)
}
```